# Notification message in SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

There's a way to show a notification message in smartgwt similar to the ones provided by [Vaadin](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#NotificationHumanized)

PD: Solution given in another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035820/gwt-notification-widget) for GWT doesn't seems to work correctly in smartgwt.

Comment: The solution provided by your link should work with SmartGWT. Why it's not working ? As far as I know, there is no native solution for that. SmartGWT offers the possibility to achieve that, post some code so we could be able to help you.

Comment: At least in an application that has smartgwt windows opened it doesn't appears in the top.

Comment: Post sample code @lujop. can't help you otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with [PD suggested solution link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035820/gwt-notification-widget) is the zindex.
SmartGWT uses high zindex values to display it's components.

The solution is to manually increment zindex of the popup in show:

```
public void show(int delayMilliseconds) {
    show();
    DOM.setIntStyleAttribute(getElement(), "zIndex", 1000000);
    startDelayedHide(delayMilliseconds);
}
```